# How to disable layout in Magento for static pages

Tags: magento, layout

I have some pages that need to be rended without all the Magento HTML stuff, just the HTML placed inside the Static Page Content section.

This is used for some ajax requests via Fancybox that needs to load only a clean HTML, no styles, no Javascript, no CSS.

In Zend I used to use "setDisableLayout".

How can I perform this task in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, it hard to suggest the best way but in your layout.xml you could use `<reference name="root">`

Take a look at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_json>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_load" name="content" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_json>
```

See [Magento for Developers: Part 4 - Magento Layouts, Blocks and Templates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)

You could also do (in your controller)

```
public function mycontrollerAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_invoices')->toHtml()
    );
}
```